# Unexpected output format in pandas.groupby.apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

does someone know why pandas behave differently when column which we use as BY in GROUPBY contains only 1 unique value? Specifically, if there is just 1 value and we return pandas.Series, returned output is basically transposed in comparison to multiple unique values:

```
dt = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-02 23:00', closed=None, freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dt.date, 'vals': range(dt.shape[0])}, index=dt)
dt1 = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-01 23:00', closed=None, freq='1H')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dt1.date, 'vals': range(dt1.shape[0])}, index=dt1)
def f(row, ):
    return row['vals']
print(df.groupby('date').apply(f).shape)
print(df2.groupby('date').apply(f).shape)
[out 1] (48,)
[out 2] (1, 24)
```

Is there some simple parameter I can use to make sure the behavior is consistent? Would it make sense to maybe sumbit it as bug-report due to inconsistency, or is it "expected" (I undestood from previous question that sometimes poor design or small part is not a bug)? (I still love pandas, just these small things can make their usage very painful)

Comment: based on your wording, it sounds like you explicitly want to return a Series? otherwise you can return a DataFrame (`return row[['vals']]`) and the shapes will be consistent

Comment: Thank you very much for consistent alternative! However it add necessity of subseting to obtain series and 50% overhead in comparison to Series :(
Also I do not understand why using Series produces inconsistent behavior...

Comment: `groupby()` has a [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) param that will produce shapes `(48,)` and `(24,)` but apparently it's being [deprecated soon](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32380): `df2.groupby('date', squeeze=True).apply(f).shape`

Comment: @tdy thanks, this works well, and there is non-deprecated version: df.groupby('date').apply(f).squeeze()

Only problem is that if you are not familiar with this, you will not expect such behavior...

Comment: nice, added as an answer including the non-deprecated version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `squeeze()`

[**`DataFrame.squeeze()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) and [**`Series.squeeze()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.squeeze.html) can make the shapes consistent:

```py
>>> df.groupby('date').apply(f).squeeze().shape
(48,)

>>> df2.groupby('date').apply(f).squeeze().shape
(24,)
```

---

#### `squeeze=True` (deprecated)

`groupby()` has a [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) param:

> `squeeze`: Reduce the dimensionality of the return type if possible, otherwise return a consistent type.

```py
>>> df.groupby('date', squeeze=True).apply(f).shape
(48,)

>>> df2.groupby('date', squeeze=True).apply(f).shape
(24,)
```

This has been [deprecated since pandas 1.1.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32380) and will be removed in the future.